# Complex postgres json order by clause

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Schema:

```
TABLE field (
  field_id serial NOT NULL,
  section_id integer,
  title text,
  type text,
  default_val json,
  rank integer,
  tiny integer,
  "values" json,
  grp_id integer,
  aggregate integer DEFAULT 1,
  enabled integer,
  deleted integer DEFAULT 0,
  "desc" text
)

TABLE entry
(
  entry_id serial NOT NULL,
  section_id integer,
  deleted integer DEFAULT 0,
  grp_id integer,
  data json,
  last_edited bigint,
  last_editor_id integer
)
```

The column `field.values` might look like this: `{0: {"rank" : 2, "title" : "asdf"}, 1: {"rank" : 1}}`

The column `entry.data` might look like this: `{250: 1, 251: 0}`

What I'd like to query:

```
SELECT entry.*
FROM entry
LEFT JOIN field ON field.field_id = 31
WHERE entry.deleted = 0 AND section_id = $1 AND grp_id = $2
ORDER BY cast(field.values#>>'{**entry.data->>250**, rank}' as numeric) ASC
```

This is the part that I don't know how to do: `**entry.data->>250**`

Is this even possible? Basically I'm trying to sort by the rank value of an index within a field that corresponds to an entry.

EDIT:

Attemped:

```
(field.values->(cast(coalesce(e.data->>'f4', '0') as numeric)))->>'rank'
```

Error: operator does not exist: json -> numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't try to write a string which some how resolves the embedded functions.  You concatenate strings to build a larger one...

```
field.values#>>('{' || entry.data->>250 || ', rank}')
```

Or, maybe easier to read?

```
(field.values->(entry.data->>250))->>'rank'
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. That syntax to escape the string was all I was looking for. I was just highlighting the code, not trying to search through the string for that or something.

Comment: And shouldn't it be: '{ || entry.data->>250 || , rank}'?

Comment: No, that's one long string, as opposed to three strings being concatenated.  There is no escaping in my exampl,  just concatenation